# How to use different ways to register an object in angulardart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

One can use a `value`, `type` or `factory` for registering an object. I have tried to find simple examples how and when to use each of a registering types, but not succeed.

It would be wonderful, if someone could give brief examples and explain the typical use cases.

Here are some links about the subject:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21245335/2777805

http://victorsavkin.com/post/72452331552/angulardart-for-angularjs-developers-introduction-to

Answer (score 2):

**type**

```dart
// old syntax
type(SomeType); // or
type(SomeInterface, implementedBy: SomType)

// new syntax
bind(SomeType); // or
bind(SomeInterface, toImplementation: SomType)
```

default, DI creates an instance and all constructor parameters (if any are resolved by DI and provided)

**value**

```dart
// created inline or e.g. passed in from somewhere as a parameter
// old syntax
value(new SomeType('xxx', 123)); 

// new syntax
bind(SomeType, toValue: new SomeType('xxx', 123));
```

if you want to to pass a previously instantiated instance. 
I usually use this for configuration settings.

**factory**

```dart
// old syntax
factory(NgRoutingUsePushState,
    (_) => new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));

// or
factory(UsersRepository, (Injector inj) => new UsersRepository(inj.get(Http)));

// new syntax
bind(NgRoutingUsePushState,toFactory:
    (_) => new NgRoutingUsePushState.value(false));
bind(UsersRepository, toFactory: (Injector inj) => new UsersRepository(inj.get(Http)));
```

(from http://victorsavkin.com/post/72452331552/angulardart-for-angularjs-developers-introduction-to)

when you want DI to delegate the instantiation to a factory function

Comment: Thank you Gunter. Could you open those examples little bit more ie. give some example code where each of types is used. I'm sorry, I'm just starting to learn these things and I just can't get a grip about the use cases.

Comment: I normally just use `type`. When I can't achieve what I want with `type` I think about using `value` (I use it for example when I want to pass around an object with configuration settings like database host/port/credentials I read from command line args or from a config file). I never used factory yet besides the first above example which I just copied from a angular.dart.tutorial (and I have never seen it being used beside those two examples above)