# Display a simple AngularDart component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'am starting to learn Dart/AngularDart and i'am trying to display a simple component following the tutorial in https://angulardart.org/ , my problem is that i got a blank page nothing is displayed.
Here is my code:

web/nasiha.dart

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'components/post/post.dart';
import 'dart:mirrors';

class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    type(PostComponent);
  }
}

void main() {
  ngBootstrap(module: new MyAppModule());
}
```

web/nasiha.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Nasiha</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nasiha.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <post></post>
    <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart" src="nasiha.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

web/components/post/post.dart

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'post',
    templateUrl:'components/post/post.html',
    cssUrl: 'components/post/post.css',
    publishAs: 'cmp_post'
)
class PostComponent {
  String text= "This is a simple text to show";
  String userName = "test";
  DateTime date= new DateTime.now();

  PostComponent(String text, String userName, DateTime date){
    this.text = text;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.date = date;
  }

  String getText(){
    return this.text;
  }
  void setText(String text){
    this.text = text;
  }
  DateTime getDate(){
    return this.date;
  }
  void setDate(DateTime date){
    this.date = date;
  }
  String getUserName(){
    return this.userName;
  }
  void setUserName(String userName){
    this.userName = userName;
  }
}
```

web/components/post/post.html

```dart
<div>
  <p ng-model="cmp_post.post_text">
  {{cmp_post.text}}
  </p>
  <div ng-model="cmp_post.post_date">
  {{cmp_post.date}}
  </div>
  <div ng-model="cmp_post.post_username">
  {{cmp_post.userName}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see an error in your code. What Angular version are you using. Does the output in DartEditor or Dartium devtools console indicate some problem? Can you add a print statement to the constructor to verify the component gets instantiated?

Comment: The `ng-model` attributes in `web/components/post/post.html` are redundant.

Comment: I'am using angular 0.0.7, i  added a print statement nothing was displayed in th console but in the console it indicate this statement C:\Users\Youssef\Downloads\Softwares\darteditor-windows-ia32\dart\chromium\Chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=52980 --user-data-dir=C:\Users\Youssef\.dartium --enable-experimental-web-platform-features --enable-html-imports --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --no-process-singleton-dialog chrome://version/
The built-in library 'dart:json' is not available on Dartium.

Comment: You should execute `pub upgrade` from the context menu on `pubspec.yaml`. You use a very old Angular version. If you get Angular 0.9.11/0.10.0 you will need to make some changes to your code because there where several breaking changes with the recent Angular update. Alternatively you can set your Angular dependency to `angular: '0.9.10'` to get the previous version and cope with the breaking changes later.
Most of the output is normal but `The built-in library 'dart:json' is not available on Dartium.` will prevent your code to run at all. Upgrading to more recent versions will solve this.

Comment: I set the dependency to angular: '0.9.10' but now got this error : Illegal argument(s): Cannot inject a primitive type of String! (resolving PostComponent -> String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should execute pub upgrade from the context menu on pubspec.yaml.
- The ng-model attributes in web/components/post/post.html are redundant.
- `PostComponent(String text, String userName, DateTime date){`
  this code is invalid.
  Either you register a class in your module that can be injected to
  the constructor or you use annotations to be able to inject primitive
  types like `String`, `int`, `double`, ... (If you want to know how inject primitive types or using annotations for injection see [How can I Dependency Inject based on type and name, with AngularDart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244644)